# Post editor loads empty

Tags: post-editor, encoding

I am running WordPress 3.8 and I recently switched server, so didn't realize when the problem creep in but most likely its the server change and I need some help figuring it out.

When I open post edit screen, the editor is empty. Switching context in Visual / Text happens but as if the editor is totally empty. There are no JS errors either.

[image]

Two things that I see happening:

1) The edit page screen always show this message when moving away from it or closing it, as if there is some pending request awaiting completion.

[image]

2) There are weird characters in a post output now. This is happening for a lot of posts.

[image]

If I dump the post content using `get_post()`, its shows up fine without any weird characters.

Also if I dump the database and import on my local, everything works just fine. So I think there is some issue with the server only, perhaps a charset encoding issue?

Ruled out any plugin causing it by disabling all plugins.

Also not sure if its related, but there was some issue with concatenation of scripts and I had to add `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );` to make scripts load correctly.

I am not sure where to look. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following constants to my `wp-config.php` solved the issues:

```
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```